# Need to upload an image to ftp. Does anyone know a Mono equivalent of CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL?

Tags: xamarin.ios, nsstream, cfnetwork

Need a Xamarin equivalent of:

```
NSOutputStream *networkStream = CFBridgingRelease(
                CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) url)
);
```

The required function is in `CFFTPStream.h` an equivalent of which is missing in Xamarin API.

Thanks

Comment: If you think there is a missing API function, you should submit a bug to Xamarin.  As a workaround, you can create your own binding for it.

Comment: Given the other comments, is the above API call necessary when you can use NSUrlSession instead?

Comment: NSUrlSessions only supporting http and not ftp. So we have scrapped that. Hence we are going forward with FtpWebRequest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you use the .NET framework [`FtpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class instead ?

That should solve your problem and will also make your code easier to port to other platforms (e.g. Android, Windows).

Comment: thanks for the reply. The problem I have with using the .NET framework is whether or not it supports backgrounding in the iOS platform. The NSULSession do a fantastic job of handling background.

Comment: That's a pretty good reason. `NSUrlSession` is your best bet in such case.

Comment: Using FtpWebRequest along with backgrounding since NSUrrlSessions are only supporting ftp